# ReactJS save output of a fetch to a var?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, output, fetch-api

It's me again, I'm still working on my collection project with a ReactJS frontend and NodeJS backend.

Today I'm trying to add a function `onClick` where I set a new array of `urlImages`.

In order to do that, **I must save the value output of my fetch in a variable called "obj", so I can use it again in another fetch.** The point of doing that is when I click into an image of the collection, it sets a new array of `urlImages` which will get the URL's of the image which belongs to the collection.

It shouldn't be that hard but I'm having trouble doing that; can anyone help me?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';
import Photo from './Photo';


class PhotoGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      urlImages: [],
      nomCollection: []
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3004/getUrlImages");
    const newList = await response.json();
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      ...previousState,
      urlImages: newList,
     }));
  }

  galleryPhotos() {
   if(this.state.urlImages) {
      return this.state.urlImages.map(function(urlimage) {
         return { src: urlimage.urlimage, width: 2, height: 2 }
      })
   }
}

  async onClick(event) {

    const rawObj = await fetch("http://localhost:3004/getCollectionFromUrlImage?urlimage="+event.target.src);
    const obj = await rawObj.json();

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3004/getUrlImagesFromCollection?collection="+obj[0].nom);
    const newList = await response.json();

    this.setState(previousState => ({
      ...previousState,
      urlImages: newList,
     }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Gallery axis={"xy"} photos={this.galleryPhotos()} onClick={this.onClick}/>
    )
  }
}
const photos = [];
export default PhotoGallery;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The response of my JSON is :

> [{"nom":"Cartes"}]

The console.log shows:

> 0: {nom: "Cartes"}
> length: 1
> __proto__: Array(0)

BUT the `alert(obj)` shows `undefined`.

Any help? I want the obj to be equal to "Cartes"..

Comment: wait... you used async/await and fetch properly in the componentDidMount, why didn't you use that same technique in the onclick? copy/paste without understanding?

Comment: I thought I understood well, i've also tried with async await but didn't get the result I wanted so i've tried different approaches thinking it would be different for two fetches.. =/

Comment: You'll need two awaits, just like in the first case. the fetch returns a promise, it resolves to a response that you then need to call .json() on, which also returns a promise.

Comment: yeah I've tried it but can't manage to get the value of obj to "Cartes". I've updated my original code, can you take a look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the first fetch, as you've done with the second:

```
const rawObj = await fetch("http://localhost:3004/getCollectionFromUrlImage?urlimage="+event.target.src);
const obj = await rawObj.json();
```

The second fetch in your `onClick` method is running before your server has had a chance to respond to the first fetch, because you don't `await` it.

Comment: hey man, I've tried your approach but when I do a console.log() it shows me the promise values. I think there's still a thing I don't understand about the fetch, shouldn't the var obj be equal to "Cartes" now? or atleast an array which contains the string ?

Comment: Please see my edit, I forgot that `json()` also returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks I've edited it again and I get an array with the first string as "Cartes". But forgive my lack of knowledge, how can I just put the string value of the array in the variable? The response is an array 
right, so shouldn't obj[0] gives me back the first value? I'm confused

Comment: Looking at your data structure `obj[0]` will get you `{nom: 'Cartes'}`, then you can get the string by doing `obj[0].nom`

Comment: Oh my god i finally managed to make it work. Thanks a lot for your time and your help. Problem is now resolved and I've updated the solution in my original post